# Unterschied zwischen "Grund" und "Ursache"

Tags: difference, meaning, noun

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Wörtern *Grund* und *Ursache*?

Comment: Hast du denn eine Idee? Mit einem Wörterbuch sollte sich das gut klären lassen.

Comment: Glaube nicht, dass da ein Wörterbuch viel hilft.

Comment: This is simply  the difference between "reason" and "cause"

Answer (score 8):

Ich will hier nur mein Verständnis dieser beiden Wörter als Muttersprachler erklären, ins Wörterbuch kannst ja du selbst schauen. Ich bin nicht der Meinung, dass diese beiden Wörter austauschbar sind. Das mag in manchen Fällen zwar möglich sein, im Allgemeinen jedoch nicht.

*Grund* kann u. a. im Sinn von *Beweggrund* verwendet werden, z. B. in

> Welchen Grund hattest du, das zu tun?

Das Wort „Ursache“ wäre hier fehl am Platz. *Grund* kann auch für „Begründung“ verwendet werden, z. B. in

> Was war der offizielle Grund für diesen Beschluss?

Auch hier wäre das Wort *Ursache* unpassend, weil hier eher „Begründung“ oder „Rechtfertigung“ gemeint ist.

Bei *Ursache* geht es oft um tiefere, komplexere Zusammenhänge als bei *Grund*. Zum Beispiel in dem Satz

> Was waren die Ursachen des Ersten Weltkrieges?

wäre ein Ersetzen von *Ursachen* durch *Gründe* zwar theoretisch möglich, der entstehende Satz würde jedoch irgendwie trivialer klingen, weil *Grund* oft für alltäglichere Dinge als für Weltkriege verwendet wird.

Zusammenfassend kann ich sagen, dass es mir leichter fällt, Beispiele zu finden, bei denen beide Wörter unterschiedlich verwendet werden, als Beispiele, wo beide austauschbar sind.

Comment: Dem Satz zum Weltkrieg widerspreche ich befremdet. Das muss dein persönlicher Geschmack sein, der hier spricht. Das wäre auch ganz fremd für die Plastizität der Sprache, dass man ein Wort mit der passenden Bedeutung bei alltäglichen Dingen verwendet, wobei Alltägliches auch kein Gegensatz zu Tiefe und Komplexität ist. Auch sind solche Kategorisierungen viel zu kontextabhängig, als dass man ohne einen solchen derartige Aussagen machen könnte.

Answer (score 3):

Der Unterschied ist schon signifikant:

Eine Ursache steht immer in direktem Zusammenhang mit der Wirkung, daher sagt man ja auch Ursache und Wirkung. Ein Grund beeinflusst nur die Wirkung oder den letztendlichen Effekt.

Beispiel:

> Wegen eines Sturmes hat ein Baum ein Auto getroffen.

Die Ursache für das kaputte Auto war der umfallende Baum und damit der Sturm.

Ohne Sturm hätte es einer anderen Ursache bedurft, damit der Baum umfällt.

Es kann aber noch Gründe für das Geschehen geben, die jedoch nicht ursächlich für selbiges waren.

> Der Baum war morsch. (Sonst wäre er vielleicht nicht umgefallen.)
>
> Das Auto stand nicht am üblichen Fleck. (Sonst hätte der Baum das Auto nicht treffen können.)

Man kann sagen, ohne Ursache keine Wirkung, jedoch kann die Wirkung durch zusätzliche Gründe anders ausfallen, während die Ursache die gleiche bleibt.

> Ein gesunder Baum hätte dem Sturm vielleicht standgehalten und nur geschwankt.
>
> An einer anderen Stelle stehend wäre das Auto nicht vom Baum getroffen worden.

Des Weiteren kann ein Grund auch für die Intention einer Handlung stehen. Ich möchte etwas, daher handle ich so oder so. Ursache ist dagegen immer die Handlung selbst oder eben das Fehlen einer solchen.

Nicht zuletzt wird oft Grund synonym benutzt, wenn man eine Ursache meint, auch wenn es nicht das Gleiche ist. Umgekehrt geht das oft nicht.

**Aktion = Ursache**

**Reaktion = Wirkung**

**Gründe beeinflussen die Art und Weise der Reaktion.**

Selbstverständlich ist fast jede Aktion auch schon immer irgendeine Reaktion, die allererste Ursache findet man jedoch nicht, denn da fängt dann Glaube an.

Comment: "Man kann sagen ohne Grund keine Wirkung, jedoch kann die Wirkung durch zusätzliche Ursachen anders ausfallen, während der Grund der gleiche bleibt." Das kann man also nicht sagen? Das mit der Intention scheint mir eine belastbare Differenz, der Rest wirkt mehr zusaammengesponnen.

Comment: @userunknown Es gibt nicht zusätzliche Ursachen, da jede Wirkung nur eine Ursache hat. Daher kann man das, siehe Ihren Kommentar, nicht schreiben.

Comment: Was ist die Ursache dafür, dass so viele Jugendliche zum IS aufbrechen? Da gibt es nur eine Ursache für? Ist das ein Dogma, dass es immer nur eine Ursache gibt, oder woraus folgt das?

Comment: @user unknown Jeder Jugendliche mag mehrere Gründe haben, aber es gibt eine letztendliche Ursache für den Aufbruch. Für das Aufbrechen vieler Jugendlicher gibt es viele Ursachen. Genau so viele wie Jugendliche aufbrechen, auch wenn manche aus dem gleichen Grund bzw. den gleichen Gründen aufbrechen.

Comment: Was ist denn eine letztendliche Ursache? Muss man sich das wie bei der Dominosteinkaskade vorstellen, wo die Ursache für das Fallen von Stein x das Fallen von Stein x-1 ist, aber die letztendliche Ursache ist das Fallen des ersten Steins? Und wieso fiel dieser? Weil der Aufbauer versehentlich dagegenstieß? Aber wieso passierte ihm dieser Fehler? Übermüdung? Ablenkung? Kann nicht beides zusammengekommen sein? Ist die letztendliche Ursache immer nur der Urknall?

Comment: @ userunknown Naja, bisher wurde hier nach dem Unterschied zwischen Grund und Ursache gefragt... Dass der Baum aufs Auto fallen konnte hatte den Grund, dass es dort geparkt war. Ein Grund für das Umfallen des Baumes war ggfs. Morschsein deselben. Die Ursache, dass er letzendlich fiel war der Sturm. Dieser hat wiederum auch eine Ursache. Falls Sie kein Interesse haben auf Argumente auch einzugehen sollten wir das lassen. MfG

Comment: Die Morschheit des Baumes hat auch wieder Ursachen, und der Sturm ist nicht die Ursache des Morschseins. Wäre er nicht morsch wäre er stehen geblieben. Hätte es keinen Sturm gegeben wäre er auch stehen geblieben.

Comment: Wo ist jetzt der Widerspruch? Ich sagte ja bereits, dass es Grunde gibt, die die Wirkung einer Ursache beeinflussen: Bsp. Baum morsch + Sturm -> Baum fällt. Baum nicht morsch + Sturm -> Baum bleibt stehen. Ein Streichholz in ein offenes Fass Benzin zu werfen entfaltet als Ursache wohl nur dann eine grosse Wirkung, falls es vorher angezündet wurde. Der Grund für den Knall wäre das ein brennendes Streicholz hinein fiel. Die Ursache für Hineinfallen, das Hineinwerfen oder Fallen lassen. Die Ursache für das Brennen, das Anzünden.

Comment: Ja, Du baust jetzt ein Beispiel mit einer intentionalen Handlung um auf eine einzelne Ursache zu kommen. Der Täter ist vielleicht ein frustierter, entlassener Angestellter, der von seiner Frau verlassen wurde und dessen Hund gestorben ist, der sich frustriert Luft gemacht hat. Es mag manchmal eine Ursache geben und manchmal mehrere.

Answer (score 2):

Die Wörter sind schon sehr ähnlich und können weitesgehend gegeneinander ausgetauscht werden. Hier ein Versuch, die Wörter mal aufzulösen:

**Grund / Reason**

Beantwort im Wesentlichen die Frage „Warum?“. Liefert eine schlichte Begründung/Erklärung, warum etwas eingetreten ist.

**Ursache / Cause**

Die *Sache, wo etwas seinen Ursprung hat*. Referenziert also den Ausgangspunkt, wodurch etwas anderes beeinflusst/bewirkt/veranlasst wurde.

---

Zugegeben, so wirklich unterscheiden tun sich die Wörter nicht. Und genau genommen könnte *Grund* mit *Ursache* definiert werden, und umgekehrt. Selbiges gilt auch fürs Englische. Vielleicht hilft ein Beispiel mehr:

> Warum warst du zu spät?
>   Grund: Der Bus war verspätet.
>   Ursache: Der Bus war defekt.

Anmerkung: Man kann den Defekt des Busses auch als Erklärung/Begründung (sprich Grund) ansehen, ich fokussiere hier aber mehr auf 'die Einwirkung des Defekts auf die Pünktlichkeit des Busses', daher Ursache.

Comment: Der letzte Abschnitt ist faktisch nicht richtig. Die Ursache (und der Grund) für mein "Zu-spät-kommen" ist das "Zu-Spät-Kommen" des Busses. Der Defekt ist die Grund für dieses "Zu-Spät-Kommen". Mittelbar natürlich für mein eigenes ZSK verantwortlich aber so wie du das da einander gegenüberstellst, kann ich nicht zustimmen.

Comment: @Emanuel Natürlich hätte ich Grund und Ursache auch umkehren können–das habe ich auch im Absatz davor erwähnt. Mein Punkt mit dem Beispiel ist ja lediglich, dass es einen Auslöser (Defekt), der unmittelbar bewirkt hat, dass der Bus zu spät war. Ich hätte es auch als Grund deklarieren können und damit die Frage des Warums beantworten. Das ich zu spät wegen des Busses bin, ist aber im Allgemeinen dann immer die Antwort auf das Warum (Grund), eher selten wird das als Ursache abgestempelt. "Die schlichte Verspätung des Busses bewirkte, dass ich zu spät bin" ist nicht das, was man i.d.R. ausdrückt.

Comment: Der Punkt ist, dass "Grund" eben beides sein kann... cause und reason, während "Ursache" im engen Sinne nur "cause" ist. Das wird in deiner Antwort nicht klar. Da hilft auch das Beispiel nicht.

Answer (score 1):

Es ist schon sehr schwierig, die Wörter Grund und Ursache von einander abzugrenzen. Eigentlich sind die beiden Wörter bedeutungsgleich. Idiomatisch dürfte es aber schon Unterschiede geben, so sprechen wir z.B.
von Brandursache und Todesursache. Ich habe gerade im DWDS nachgeschaut. Bei Ursache gibt Pfeifer im etymologischen Teil an, dass Ursache ursprünglich der Sprache der Juristen entstammt und später auch in die Normalsprache eingedrungen ist. Das dürfte der Grund sein, warum wir von Todesursache oder Brandursache reden oder lesen. Hier haben die beiden Wörter mehr amtlichen oder offiziellen Charakter.

Ich glaube nicht, dass man beide Wörter mit unterschiedlichen Definitionen abgrenzen kann. Siehe Worterklärungen bei DWDS, denn im Grunde haben sie die gleiche Bedeutung. Und eine Daumenregel für Lernende gibt es schon gar nicht. Ein Lerner kann eigentlich nur genauer hinschauen, wann Ursache und wann Grund gebraucht wird.

http://www.dwds.de/?qu=ursache

http://www.dwds.de/?qu=grund

Answer (score 0):

Abgesehen von den weiteren Bedeutungen von *Grund* (z.B. Grund und Boden) ist der Hauptunterschied zwischen *Grund* und *Ursache* der folgende:

- *Grund* ist ein Allerweltswort, das umganssprachlich fast immer passt. Bei genauerer Differenzierung wird es vor allem in einem sozialen Kontext verwendet: Ein Grund (auch Beweggrund) ist dann etwas, das einen Menschen (oder ein anderes Wesen mit freiem Willen) dazu veranlasst, etwas zu tun. Das, was aus einem Grund geschieht, wird oft als Folge bezeichnet. Die Verbalisierung eines (wirklichen oder angeblichen) Grundes nennt man Begründung.
- *Ursache* wird vor allem in einem wissenschaftlichen oder technischen Kontext verwendet: Eine Ursache ist etwas, was bewirkt, dass etwas anderes geschieht. Das, was aus einer Ursache geschieht, wird fast immer als Wirkung bezeichnet.

In den meisten Fällen, in denen das eine Wort passt, kann man auch das andere verwenden. Meist wird aber das unauffälligere Wort *Grund* oder das besser passende der beiden bevorzugt. Oder beide werden zusammen verwendet, insbesondere kontrastierend. Bei kontrastierender Verwendung liegt ein Grund näher am bewirkten Ereignis und ist direkter mit ihm verbunden; eine Ursache hat mehr mit dem großen Zusammenhang zu tun.

> Der Grund für den Absturz war Materialermüdung in einem Bauteil des Triebwerks. Die Ursache war, dass das Flugzeug nicht richtig gewartet wurde.
>
> Heute bin ich zu spät zur Arbeit gekommen. Der Grund war ein verspäteter Bus. Die Ursache war, dass ich gestern Abend zu lange aufgeblieben bin und deshalb heute Morgen zu knapp losgefahren bin.
>
> Ursachen des Ersten Weltkriegs waren verbreiteter Nationalismus, die allgemeine Aufrüstung und das Gefühl der Unvermeidbarkeit eines Krieges. Anlass des Ersten Weltkriegs war das Attentat von Sarajevo. Gründe des Ersten Weltkriegs ("Kriegsgrund") waren die Ereignisse der Julikrise, die auf das Attentat folgte.